# Why does my badge count disappear every time I enter Lifehacks Meta?

Tags: bug

I have four badges in Lifehacks Meta. When I visit the site, they're not beside my user profile at the top of the page. If I enter the Help center and click on Tour, they reappear. It doesn't happen on any of my other sites. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have four badges on the *regular* Lifehacks site. You have no badges (though you'll likely get one, since I upvoted your question) on Lifehacks *Meta*.

Even though reputation on Main and Meta sites are the same (since, barring [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), there isn't any rep on Meta sites), badges are counted separately. (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117523/266359) for why)

The reason clicking on the "Tour" restores your badges is because the "Tour" takes place on the Main site, not on the Meta site.